# Error while trying to store data from file to object array(Java)

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to read in from a .txt file that has students' first names, last names and averages. I'm trying to read the data and store them in an array of objects, however, I am running into the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bubblesort.Bubblesort.readin(Bubblesort.java:34)
    at bubblesort.Bubblesort.main(Bubblesort.java:49)
```

This is my code

```
package bubblesort;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Bubblesort {

public class students{
   public String name;
   public String lastname;
   public double average;
}    

public static students[]readin(students[] studentinfo){
    String info = "src/Files/numname.txt";
    int count = 0;
    String catcher = null;
    try {
            File InputFile = new File(info); //createsa new file input
            Scanner Input = new Scanner(InputFile);   
            for (;count<25;count++){
                studentinfo[count].name = Input.nextLine();
                studentinfo[count].lastname = Input.nextLine();
                studentinfo[count].average = Input.nextDouble();
                catcher=Input.nextLine();
            }

    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error reading in file");
    }
    return studentinfo;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        students[] studentinfo = new students[25];
        readin(studentinfo);  
    }   
}
```

If someone could please help me understand I would appreciate it a lot, thank you

Comment: You have created array that holds 25 Student type object, you need to create each student object before setting some property of it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing `studentinfo[count]` in your for loop, its `null`. Performing operation of  `studentinfo[count].name` is giving you the `NullPointerException`.

You need to initialize a `students` object and assign it to properly -

```
for (;count<25;count++){
   students student = new students();
   student.name = Input.nextLine();
   student.lastname = Input.nextLine();
   student.average = Input.nextDouble();

   studentinfo[count] = student;

   catcher=Input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: `students student = new students();` will not work because `students` is an inner class.

Comment: I know.. its just to point where the problem is.. how to tackle it is upto op.

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurred because you have not initialize each `Student` object inside the array

*Notes at your code:*

1. Use `try-with-resource` to take the advantage of `AutoCloseable` interface.
2. There is no need to send `studentinfo` info array and get it again.
3. Use `while` loop instead of `for` loop when you are reading input to avoid exception.
4. `Class` name must start with capital latter by Java convention.
5. In future, try to make the file you read in the form of all data about one `student` in one line separated by any special character like `,` So you can avoid mismatch number of line

Consider the following code:

```
public class Bubblesort {

    class Student {
        public String name;
        public String lastname;
        public double average;

        public String toString() {
            return "First name: " + name + ", Last name: " + lastname + ", Average: " + average;

        }
    }

    public static Student[] readStudentsInfo() {
        String info = "src/Files/numname.txt";
        int count = 0;
        Student[] studentInfo = new Student[25];
        Bubblesort outerClass = new Bubblesort();

        try (Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(new File(info))) {
            while (inputScanner.hasNext()) {
                studentInfo[count] = outerClass.new Student();
                studentInfo[count].name = inputScanner.nextLine();
                studentInfo[count].lastname = inputScanner.nextLine();
                studentInfo[count].average = inputScanner.nextDouble();
                inputScanner.nextLine();
                count++;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading in file");
        }
        return studentInfo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] studentInfo = readStudentsInfo();

        for (Student student : studentInfo) {
            System.out.println(student);
        }

    }
}
```